# laravel 5.5 eloquent query builder build wrong query when storing url with query string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have an eloquent model with `url` and `data`, and other standard laravel fields.

then i do:

```
        $cache = new \App\Cache();
        $cache->url = $this->url;
        $cache->data = json_encode($data);
        $cache->save();
```

when `url` have no query string, it works perfectly, but when `url` have query string, laravel generate wrong query such as:

original data:

```
$this->url = 'https://some-url.com?param1=val1&param2=val2';
$data = ['some' => 'long', 'json' => 'data'];
```

turns to:

```
insert into `cache` (`url`, `data`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (
    https://some-url.com{"some":"long","json":"data"}param1=val1&param2=val2, 
    2019-01-07 07:38:15, 
    ?, 
    ?
)
```

as you can see, the encoded json is put on the wrong place (on the `?` of the query string)

what did i do wrong? or this is a bug?

note: i'm using mysql

update: removed the error string as it distracting to the main issue

Comment: What is the size of  ```url``` column in database?

Comment: url is string (191), data is longtext, the json should go to data, not to url

Comment: I guess you have to increase size of ```url``` column. Try doing that.

Comment: too long is not the problem, problem is the placement of the json

Comment: Can encode only JSON part and then try saving in db.

Comment: @am05mhz error is pretty clear, it is indicating your url column is too short to contain the url data,,just increase the size of url column

Comment: nope, the url part is must be saved too, @Sohel0415 please read more carefully, the cause of data too long is wrong placement of data

Comment: @am05mhz Laravel use data binding automatically,,so there is no issue like you said,,,why don't you try increasing the size or changing your column to type text

Comment: @Sohel0415 that is the issue, its automatic and its wrong

Comment: This has nothing to do with length of the fields. It's because Laravel uses `?` as placeholders for data in queries.

Comment: @Jerodev finally someone gets it, do you know proper way to do this?

Comment: @am05mhz can you add the value of `url` and `data`?

Comment: why is the `$data` right in the middle of the `url`? That would not happen by the code shared alone. Do you have any attribute mutators?

Comment: oh my god!! `?` mark on `url` causing the problem

Comment: yeah, sorry, manoj suggestion was a miss

Comment: @am05mhz can you please try increasing your column size as i have replicate your problem exactly, after increasing column size, its working properly

Comment: @apokryfos no attribute mutators, not sure how to do that either

Comment: @Sohel0415, please also check the data, is the json in the `url` field, or in the `data` field?

Comment: @am05mhz its working exactly it should work

Comment: @Sohel0415 wow, that is very wierd, field changed to longtext and it can store data correctly, thanks, please submit your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out its a bug on the sql logger that produce wrong sql snipet. the main error is just that the field length does not fit the data length as @Sohel0415 suggested.

so the logger is misleading me to think that the generated query is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to store the URL like that in DB

```
$url_string = $this->url;
$cache->url = '{$url_string}';
```

It will be work for URLs

Comment: sorry, was a mistake, this do save the data, but the url is saved as just `'{$url}'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should type cast the url as string and then save it or use the standard create() method this should work. I have used in one of my projects with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use urlencode() function.
Try save your url with encoding.

```
$cache->url = urlencode($this->url);
```

and later you can get it with urldecode() function.

Comment: might do this work around if there is no other options